# Error while implementing postgresql on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I get the following error while implementing rake db:migrate

```
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

I have created two tables in the database using postgresql.

My database.yml is

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: shop_development
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: 

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: shop_test
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: 

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: shop_production
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password:
```

I have also run the command such as:

```
C:\Sites\shop>gem install 'pg'
Successfully installed pg-0.14.1-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for pg-0.14.1-x86-mingw32...
Installing RDoc documentation for pg-0.14.1-x86-mingw32...
```

but this is still giving me the same error.

My gemfile has the following :

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
    activesupport (3.2.11)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.7.6)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.21)
    multi_json (1.5.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.11)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      activerecord (= 3.2.11)
      activeresource (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.11)
    railties (3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.3)
    rdoc (3.12.1)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.2.5)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.7-x86-mingw32)
    thor (0.17.0)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.35)
    uglifier (1.3.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  jquery-rails
  rails (= 3.2.11)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  sqlite3
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

My gemfile has the following content:-

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# gem 'sqlite3'

 gem 'pg'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

my bundle install show the following:-

```
C:\Sites\shop>bundle install
Using rake (10.0.3)
Using i18n (0.6.1)
Using multi_json (1.5.0)
Using activesupport (3.2.11)
Using builder (3.0.4)
Using activemodel (3.2.11)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.5)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.2.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.11)
Using mime-types (1.21)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.12)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.11)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.35)
Using activerecord (3.2.11)
Using activeresource (3.2.11)
Using bundler (1.0.22)
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
Using json (1.7.6)
Using rdoc (3.12.1)
Using thor (0.17.0)
Using railties (3.2.11)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using jquery-rails (2.2.1)
Using pg (0.14.1)
Using rails (3.2.11)
Using sass (3.2.5)
Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
Using uglifier (1.3.0)
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem
is installed.
```

Comment: can you add your Gemfile to the question?

Comment: @jvnill i have edited the question.can you please help me

Comment: that's Gemfile.lock. Gemfile is cleaner so can you use that instead?

Comment: Hi Prathamesh, I've cleaned up some of your code formatting, but please have a look at the formatting guide, it will make your questions easier to read: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: my gemfile has the following content:-
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

Comment: can you edit your question and add that gemfile?

Comment: @ jvnill i have edited my question and added gem 'pg' in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this..

```
 sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client postgresql-contriblibpq-dev
```

Comment: @ vijikumar thank you now it is working.can u please tell me how to start postgresql console in ruby on rail.ie can u specify the command

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `bundle install`?
It looks like `sqlite3` is currently installed but `pg` isn't.

If you're moving data from `sqlite3` to `pg` then have a look at this railscast: [Migrating to PostgreSQL](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql)

Comment: yes i have run bundle install
C:\Sites\shop>bundle install
...
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem
is installed.

Comment: how do i start a postgresql console from ruby on rails command prompt

Comment: I can see the gem in your Gemfile, but not in the list of installed gems that you posted.

Comment: @ mind.blank  i have edited my question with the list of installed gems please let me know if there is any gem there has to be added

Comment: Not sure then. By the way, why are all your databases development?